# C# threads when executing many tasks in Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#, async-await

What will happen if, on a single thread, I do this:

```c#
await Task.WhenAll(items.select(x => SomeAsyncMethod(x)))

// Where SomeAsyncMethod is defined like this (writeAsync is pure async io)
async Task SomeAsyncMethod(Item item){
  await myDevice.writeAsync(...).ConfigureAwait(false);
  //do some cpu intensive stuff...
}
```

and say there are 10.000 items in `items`. When each of the `SomeAsyncMethod` continue after the await, then it does so on a thread from the thread pool. So when many of the `SomeAsyncsMethod`s return will several threads from the thread pool then be taken simultaneously, or will only a single thread execute "do some CPU intensive stuff" in `SomeAsyncMethod` at any given moment in this case?

UPDATE: Ok here is a sample program. When I test this on a PC with 8 logical cores, then minthreads is 12 or 13 and maxthreads ends in the 35-40 range. 
So it looks as if up to 4 threads will be created pr logical core. It does not matter if 10.000 or 100.000 files are created - the same max number of threads is used - maybe this is because all the tasks queue up waiting for access to the file system ?. Please note, that this program will create lots of small files in c:\tmp\asynctest:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var myDevice = new MyDevice();
            var ints = new List<int>();
            for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
                ints.Add(i);
            }
            var task = Task.WhenAll(ints.Select(i => myDevice.WriteTextAsync(i.ToString())));
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Max thread count = " + myDevice.MaxThreadCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Min thread count = " + myDevice.MinThreadCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class MyDevice {
        public ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> ThreadIds;
        public int MaxThreadCount;
        public int MinThreadCount = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
        public async Task WriteTextAsync(string text) {
            var filePath = @"c:\tmp\asynctest\" + text + ".txt";
            var encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)) {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                MaxThreadCount = Math.Max(MaxThreadCount, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
                MinThreadCount = Math.Min(MinThreadCount, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update 2. Now if I start multiple threads that each do lots of aysnc io tasks simultaneously, then it does not look as if more threads in total are used compared to the single threaded example in update 1. In the test I just ran, where 10.000 files are created each by 4 threads, then max threads was 41 and min threads 12 - so there seems to be some central control of how many threads are used for async task continuations. Here is a the example where 4 threads starts 10.000 async operations each:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication4 {
    internal class Program {
        private static void Main(string[] args) {
            var myDevice = new MyDevice();
            var ints = new List<int>();
            const int limit = 10000;
            for (var i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                ints.Add(i);
            }

            List<Task> jobs = new List<Task>();
            for (var j = 0; j < 4*limit; j+=limit) {
                var jobid = j;
                jobs.Add(Task.Run(() => Runjob(ints, myDevice, jobid)));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(jobs.ToArray());

            Console.WriteLine("Max thread count = " + myDevice.MaxThreadCount);
            Console.WriteLine("Min thread count = " + myDevice.MinThreadCount);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void Runjob(List<int> ints, MyDevice myDevice, int jobid) {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting job " + jobid);
            var task = Task.WhenAll(ints.Select(i => myDevice.WriteTextAsync((jobid+i).ToString())));
            task.Wait();
            Console.WriteLine("Finished job " + jobid);
        }
    }

    public class MyDevice {
        public int MaxThreadCount;
        public int MinThreadCount = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count;
        public async Task WriteTextAsync(string text) {
            var filePath = @"c:\tmp\asynctest\" + text + ".txt";
            var encodedText = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);
            using (var sourceStream = new FileStream(filePath,
                FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None, bufferSize: 4096, useAsync: true)) {
                await sourceStream.WriteAsync(encodedText, 0, encodedText.Length).ConfigureAwait(false);
                MaxThreadCount = Math.Max(MaxThreadCount, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
                MinThreadCount = Math.Min(MinThreadCount, Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It all depends on. SynchronisationContext.

Comment: The easiest way to find out would be to just try it. Add a `Debug.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` and find out.

Comment: Ok, lets say I do a ConfigureAwait false so that the context is not required (i edit the question now to refelct that).

Comment: If it is a large number of items like you are stating 10 000. You mighthit thread starvation. Also, we need to take into account few things like: ThreadPool can scale according to circumstances. It can take time to spin up that many tasks where some of the first ones will be already completed and releasing thread for other tasks.

Comment: I have not tested this, but I see no reason why multiple threads should be taken. Imho, only one thread executes the work.

Comment: The operation may use no threads at all if `writeAsync` is truly asynchronous, ie it uses the driver's/OS's support for completion pools. `await` doesn't make anything run asynchronously, it only *awaits* for an already asynchronous job to finish

Comment: If `writeAsync` uses "fake asynchrony", ie it uses `Task.Run` to run something on the background, it's up to the TaskScheduler. It will try to keep all cores occupied without causing thrashing. What does `writeAsync` do ?

Comment: Final comment: The `//do some cpu intensive stuff...` runs on a thread that's decided by the type of application. With desktop applications, that is the *original UI thread*. If you want to process the device data in parallel you should extract the processing stuff to another method that can be run with `Task.Run` or better yet, `Parallel.ForEach`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely scenario is that the "CPU instensive stuff" will each happen on a random thread-pool thread - and if it's truly CPU-bound, you'll get about 1-2 threads per a logical core doing the work.

The key point is that while the continuation to the original task (`Task.WhenAll`) will run back on the UI thread (if there *is* a synchronization context, of course), the continuations to the individual I/O operations will be posted on the thread-pool, since you explicitly requested the synchronization context to be ignored (`ConfigureAwait(false)`).

However, there is also a chance that everything will run on the original thread - if the I/O request completes synchronously. In that case, no asynchronous dispatch is done, and there is no opportunity for the tasks to switch threads. If you need to ensure parallelisation, you must use `Task.Run` explicitly.

It should also be noted that this is mostly implementation dependent, and not something  you can rely on. It might also be a bad approach for a heavily asynchronous-I/O application, since you might be running the CPU intensive stuff on a thread from the I/O thread-pool - disturbing the framework balancing of threads in the thread-pool, and preventing new asynchronous responses from coming through until you're finished with your work. This is especially true if the work you're doing *isn't* pure CPU work - blocking on a thread-pool thread can be quite painful on something like a web server, for example.

Comment: Ok thanks. Interesting that 1-2 threads pr. core will do the work. This means that you can end up with multi-threaded execution even though you only do async IO code from a single thread. Good to be aware of.

Comment: My updates to the original question indicates that it is more like 3 threads per logical core.

Comment: @StigSchmidtNielsson Yeah, of course - if you don't have a synchronization context, how would you synchronize the execution? That's what synchronization contexts are for - it's a bit weird after so much time designing single-threaded applications, but synchronization is the special case. If you aren't explicit about synchronization boundaries, you must make no assumptions about what happens in what order. If you want to marshal the continuations back to a single thread of execution, use a synchronization context - that gives you effectively single-threaded asynchronous code.

Comment: @StigSchmidtNielsson And your method for measuring the threads isn't very useful. You're checking all the OS process threads, which do not map 1:1 to managed threads, your measurement and recording isn't thread-safe, and you're including all the threads (garbage collector, main thread, UI...), rather than just the ones involved in your continuations. `ThreadPool.GetMaxThreads` would be more useful, and make sure to update your numbers in a thread-safe manner. Also, you might want to actually include some serious CPU work in the continuation - right now, it's dominated by overhead.