# Task execution dependent upon the waiting mechanism?

Tags: c#, multithreading, plinq

Here's the pseudo-code that I'm running:

Variant #1:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (...)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        doWork();
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel()).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    // process results/handle errors
    ...
});
```

Variant #2:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (...)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        doWork();
    });
    tasks.Add(task);
}

Task.WhenAll(tasks.AsParallel()).Wait();

// process results/handle errors
...
```

My question is, why does the way `doWork` is invoked appears *radically* different between #1 and #2?  Is it by design and I'm just not understanding how this is supposed to work?

My (apparently failed) understanding/presumption was that `doWork` would be invoked in a multi-threaded/async fashion, parallel-if-available, in *both* scenarios, the only difference being that *the calling code* would be waiting for completion differently.  But how the tasks are *actually executed* would be the same, because they are scheduled/"run" the same way.

But from what I can tell after debugging both versions of the code, variant #1 results in `doWork` being invoked in a true parallel/fully-multithreaded fashion, whereas variant #2 seems to be acting like it's a single-threaded, sequential execution of each task.

What am I missing?

Comment: Get rid of the `AsParallel` for starters, that doesn't belong here. `WhenAll` takes an `IEnumerable` or array. Then take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41953073/224370

Comment: How do you wait for the `Task.WhenAll()` to complete in variant #1? I’m aware `ContinueWith()` will only execute then, but how are you preventing your app/method from exiting?

Comment: @IanMercer - thank you for the reference to that other answer; the part about it running on the same thread (when synchronous) actually answers my question.  The documentation for `Wait` simply says "waits for the Task to complete execution" and doesn't mention anything about single- vs multi-threading...

Comment: @sellotape, I wasn't waiting there at all, having moved all the result-processing code into the body of `ContinueWith` handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.AsParallel()` is `LINQ` multithreading extension, it has nothing to do with `Task`. `Task.Run(...)` itself is sufficient for most cases and can be used with or without `LINQ`.

Mixing both `AsParallel()` and `Task.Run()` is dangereous thing to do unless you sure what you're doing: with no efforts it might significantly degrade your performace rather than make it better as you expect.

Lastly, don't `Wait()` `Task`: it will be forcibly executed in a regular synchronous fashion, thus cancelling all the `Task`'s benefits.